# Changing component of electric field in electromagnetic wave

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, speed-of-light

In a $3D$ space,we know that when a charged particle moves/or accelerates,electric field changes in direction and magnitude. The electric field vectors are $3$ dimensional. So when we see an electromagnetic wave,we see electric field in $x$ axis and magnetic field in $y$ axis. Now,which component of electric field $E_x,E_y,E_z$ is in the seen $x$ axis? If electric field is a $3D$ vector,how can the change be shown with only one component changing?

I read somewhere that a particular direction in space is fixed as $x$ axis,and then it is the oscillation of $y$ component of electric field which is what we see in the electromagnetic wave. My question is why is it only the $y$ component? Don't the $x$ and $z$ component of electric field change? Kindly enlighten me with the proper concepts.

Comment: for simplicity of explanation they show polarized waves. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_radiation#Properties